# WIndows Antivirus reports Arp Cache Poisoning Attack by Android device

Tags: security, 7.0-nougat, malware, miui, antivirus

A Windows computer running ESET reports Arp Cache Poisoning Attack by the IP of my android phone.
It's Redmi Note 4,
MIUI 9 Global Stable,
Android 7.0.
I scanned it with Avast, Malwarebytes, MIUI Security App, Google Play Protect. I didn't find any virus.
I scanned the ports with nmap. Nothing suspicious.
My question is what can cause it?